# Netty: suggest to insert markReaderIndex() before call FrameDecoder.decode() in FrameDecoder.java

Tags: netty

Current code, before call `resetReaderIndex()` for waiting more data, we has to call `markReaderIndex()` at first line in `decode()` of child class of `FrameDecoder`.

Could you insert `cumulation.markReaderIndex();` before `Object frame = decode(context, channel, cumulation);` in `FrameDecoder.java` as follow marked by"<<<<<"? it is useful and important for beginner. thanks:

```
//org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.java:
private void callDecode(
        ChannelHandlerContext context, Channel channel,
        ChannelBuffer cumulation, SocketAddress remoteAddress) throws Exception {

    while (cumulation.readable()) {
        int oldReaderIndex = cumulation.readerIndex();
        cumulation.markReaderIndex();//WangHongguangAdd20120711<<<<<<<<<<<<
        Object frame = decode(context, channel, cumulation);
        if (frame == null) {
            if (oldReaderIndex == cumulation.readerIndex()) {
                // Seems like more data is required.
                // Let us wait for the next notification.
                break;
            } else {
                // Previous data has been discarded.
                // Probably it is reading on.
                continue;
            }
            ...
        }

        unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(context, remoteAddress, frame);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be a bad idea as we would maybe destroy a mark that the user set by himself.